# How to get columns with values from second list which is contain in first list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable

I have two list. First list has matched column which is available in second list. 
I want to show matched columns with values from second list.

[image]

```
            List<string> _filtredData = new List<string>();

            _filtredData.Add("Broker");
            _filtredData.Add("Loaction");
            _filtredData.Add("StandardLineItem");
            _filtredData.Add("Section");

            foreach (DataColumn _dtCol in FinalDiffData.Columns)
            {
                if (matchedItems.Contains(_dtCol.ToString()))
                {
                    _filtredData.Add(_dtCol.ToString());
                }
            }
```

_filtredData -> contains matched columns which available in Second list.

FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable() -> this is secondlist.

```
        List<string> _filtredData = new List<string>();

        _filtredData.Add("Broker");
        _filtredData.Add("Loaction");
        _filtredData.Add("StandardLineItem");
        _filtredData.Add("Section");

        foreach (DataColumn _dtCol in FinalDiffData.Columns)
        {
            if (matchedItems.Contains(_dtCol.ToString()))
            {
                    _filtredData.Add(_dtCol.ToString());
            }
        }

        var shortedListMismatchElementLocal = _filtredData;

        var result = FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable().Where(p => 
        shortedListMismatchElementLocal.Any());
```

Please help me with proper answer.

---

### Edit from your last comment

FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable() list has column like

```
Broker, Loaction, StandardLineItem, Section, 2Q2019E, 3Q2019E, 4Q2019E, 2019E, 1Q2020E
```

etc as earning order. _filtredData list has

```
Broker, Loaction, StandardLineItem, Section, 2Q2019E, 3Q2019E, 4Q2019E,
```

I want to get matched column with value from FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable() which available in _filtredData list

Comment: what is matched items ?. There is option to `intersect` in Linq https://www.dotnetperls.com/intersect

Comment: What is `FinalDiffData`? Is it a `DataTable` or `List<string>` or...?

Comment: You need to compare two list. You can compare using Contains on second list. See this basic example https://dotnetfiddle.net/lBkl1Y

Comment: @haldo: FinalDiffData is a datatable which transform as 
              FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable().   FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable() is has multiple column and same 
              column which in the list _filtredData.

Comment: If would help us answer if you told us what columns are in the datatable, at least which column you're trying to match values.

Comment: @haldo: I am unable to post image. FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable() list has column like Broker, Loaction, StandardLineItem, Section, 2Q2019E, 3Q2019E, 4Q2019E, 2019E, 1Q2020E etc as earning order. _filtredData list has Broker, Loaction, StandardLineItem, Section, 2Q2019E, 3Q2019E, 4Q2019E, I want to get matched column with value from FinalDiffData.AsEnumerable() which available in _filtredData list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare a `List<string>` with a `DataTable`.  You're only interested in one column in the datatable (I'll assume the column name is "Data").

The following query will get all rows in column `"Data"` matching `_filteredData`.

```
var result = FinalDiffData
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Where(p => _filtredData.Contains(p["Data"]));  // use the actual column name here
```